# R Assign values from a data.frame to a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, merge

I have a list containing some basic characteristics of factories (like capacity, turnover). All values set initially to NULL:

```
#My List:
list.var <- list(Capacity = NULL, Production = NULL)
list <- list(Factory1 = list.var, Factory2 = list.var)
> list
$Factory1
$Factory1$Capacity
NULL

$Factory1$Production
NULL


$Factory2
$Factory2$Capacity
NULL

$Factory2$Production
NULL
```

Also I have data frames that contains the "missing" values separately for each characteristics for all factories, like that:

```
> #My Data Frame:
> df.capacity <- data.frame(Factory = c("Factory1", "Factory2"), Capacity = c(100,200))
> df.capacity
   Factory Capacity
1 Factory1      100
2 Factory2      200
```

I want to assign the capacity values in `df.capacity` to the corresponding factory in my list. The result should look like this:

```
$Factory1
$Factory1$Capacity
[1] 100

$Factory1$Production
NULL


$Factory2
$Factory2$Capacity
[1] 200

$Factory2$Production
NULL
```

How can I do this? (note that I have multiple factories and even more characteristics, thus I should do it automatically each time like left join in case of data frames). I tried to convert the data frame to a list and then combine with the original one, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From base R, you could also do:

```
modifyList(list, split(df.capacity[-1], df.capacity[1]))

$Factory1
$Factory1$Capacity
[1] 100

$Factory1$Production
NULL


$Factory2
$Factory2$Capacity
[1] 200

$Factory2$Production
NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

We could `match` to get the corresponding values and then do the assignment

```
library(purrr)
imap(list, ~  {
      .x$Capacity <- df.capacity$Capacity[match(.y, df.capacity$Factory)]
       .x})
```

---

Or with `Map` from `base R`

```
Map(function(x, y) {
         x$Capacity <- df.capacity$Capacity[match(y, df.capacity$Factory)]
         x

       },
      list, names(list))
```

-output

```
$Factory1
$Factory1$Capacity
[1] 100

$Factory1$Production
NULL


$Factory2
$Factory2$Capacity
[1] 200

$Factory2$Production
NULL
```

---

Or using a `for` loop

```
for(i in seq_along(df.capacity$Factory)) list[[df.capacity$Factory[i]]]$Capacity <- df.capacity$Capacity[i]
```